# Load custom html module with JModuleHelper::getModule in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I'm using the following code to render a joomla! module:

```
        jimport('joomla.application.module.helper');
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule('AddToCartReplacementBtn');
        echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module);
```

However it doesn't seem to work in my specific case

I'm loading a custom HTML module with the name `AddToCartReplacementBtn`. Its position is also `AddToCartReplacementBtn`

The documentation says that I can load a module by its real name or the folder.

Is there any other way of loading a module by its real name?

Comment: What is the expected output? What does `JModuleHelper::getModule('AddToCartReplacementBtn')` return? What does `JModuleHelper::renderModule($module)` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_custom','AddToCartReplacementBtn');
echo $renderer->render($module);
```